# User does not exist error while adding user to SharePoint group via REST API post request ajax

Tags: javascript, rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

```
function addthisuser(){
    var data = {
        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.User' },
        'LoginName': "martin.newman@sharepoint.com"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('HRGroupSharePoint')/users",
        method: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',  
                        'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',  
                        'odata-version': ''                                  
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert('Item added successfully');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            debugger;
            alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }); 
}
```

Using above `POST` request to add user (hard coded email against **LoginName**) ends in error saying "The user does not exist or is not unique". If the user, specified above, is given Read permission on entire site as *Unique permissions* the error still persists... Is the **LoginName** format wrong? Is anything wrong in headers?

Answer (score 0):

**LoginName** must be **Key** property of person column e.g. **i:0#.w|rib.johnson@domain.com**